# What's the RIGHT way to reference named cells in Excel 2013 VBA? (I know I'm messing this up)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a cell (Ok there's a bunch but I'm just looking at one now) named "Classes". It's "C10" by Excel's grid notation.

My code works perfectly when I reference the cell as

```
Range("C10") = "Value"
```

But when I use

```
Classes = "Value"
```

It just does nothing.

So, what's the correct way to reference a named cell by its name?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You replace the address with the named range's name:

```
Range("Classes") = "Value"
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use the square bracket shorthand for referencing ranges:

```
[Classes] = "Value"
```

So you can save on `Range` and `""`, and it also looks better (square brackets look a bit like a cell). You can also use `[C10] = "Value"`

Comment: TIL, I've never seen anyone do that in all the years of Excel

Comment: @HackSlash  LOL. You need to get out more often.

Comment: @ExcelHero, curious choice of words due to global pandemic. When I go out, I don't run in to people talking about Excel very often.

Comment: You misunderstand. Square bracket notation has been around since Joel hooked up VBA to Excel! Where have you been?